# How to negate classname with Proguard

Tags: java, proguard

I want to be able to obfuscate only a subset of classes with proguard, but am having a hard time since proguard seems to designed primarily to obfuscate everything, except for a blacklist.

However, the [proguard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#classspecification) does say:

> For additional flexibility, class names can actually be comma-separated lists of class names, with optional ! negators, just like file name filters. This notation doesn't look very Java-like, so it should be used with moderation.

but there are no examples of that.

I am trying this:

```
-keep class !**.licence.** {*;}
-keep class !**.*Licence*.** {*;}
```

but that does work.  If I remove the `!`, the patterns themselves do work (everything *else* gets obfuscated, except the above).  I have also tried with the method definitiones (`{*;}` removed), but still does not work.

Does anyone have any examples of negators on classnames?  Is there another way to tell proguard to only obfuscate specific class/package patterns (without using in-code annotations)?

Answer (score 4):

I finally figured it out on my own.   The negations must all be on one line, like this:

```
-keep class !ca.nanometrics.**.licence.**,!ca.nanometrics.**.*Licence*{*;}
```